# Having trouble with footer in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

So I made this basic page, but problem is that whatever I do with footer, the text is not centered, and also it's not fixed, when I change the height of my browser, it moves around.

Here's the code and preview:
http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/2nnyr

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to place a row within your container and a col with an offset-2 and remove pull-right. Hope this helps see below.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p class="footertext pull-right">© 2016 *******. All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the text, change the text-align from left to center in your media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bs-footer {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```